# Why do a Clojure instant uses a "-" instead of a "+" when describing timezones?

Tags: clojure

Note that in the following Clojure REPL, I input the `instant` with  "+00:00" or "+01:00" to describe the timezone information but the REPL output produces an `instant` using "-00:00" (UTC).

```
user> #inst "2016-11-12T20:33:31.000+00:00"
#inst "2016-11-12T20:33:31.000-00:00"
user> #inst "2016-11-12T20:33:31.000+01:00"
#inst "2016-11-12T19:33:31.000-00:00"
```

Is this behaviour by design?

I'm using Clojure 1.8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this issue that explains the behaviour:

http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-928

Clojure `instant` is expected to print time in UTC for now.